# Create vals in a loop with consecutive names

Tags: scala, for-loop

I want to create vals in a loop with consecutive postfixes in names: `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4` ...

With code

```
for( a <- 1 to 10){
         val 'b'+a = new Button()
      }
```

So the following happens

```
val b1 = new Button()
val b2 = new Button()
val b3 = new Button()
val b4 = new Button()
val b5 = new Button()
val b6 = new Button()
val b7 = new Button()
val b8 = new Button()
val b9 = new Button()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was suggested by Carcigenicate in the comment section, you might want to use a `List` or other similar collection / data structure:

```
(for(_ <- 0 until 10) yield new Button()).toList
```

The `toList` call is optinal, otherwise a `Range` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a list of buttons, do this:

```
val buttons = List.fill(10)(new Button())
```

Then access them by index

```
val b2 = buttons(1) // First element is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to access buttons by names then try creating a [`Map`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/maps.html)

```
val buttons = Map.from((1 to 10).map(i => s"b$i" -> new Button()))
buttons.get("b1")
```

Note we cannot declare a name of a value dynamically (at runtime) so the following is a syntax error

```
val "x"+1 = 42 // compile-time error
```

The key concept to understand is the difference between what happens at *compile-time* versus *runtime*, that is, the difference between facilities provided *before* the program runs versus *after* the program runs. Introducing a name of a value as part of [value definition](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions) is a purely compile-time concept.